# Vue.js multiple select to populate another multiple select

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is it possible to have two multiple select fields, and the second select options will be filled based upon what is selected in the first select?

Explanation:

Each category has many descriptions related to them.

The main select menu is called "categories", and the options are static, they don't change.
The second select menu is called "descriptions".

I can select as many categories as I want. If I select one category, the second select menu will have all descriptions related to that category as the options. When I select another category in the category select field, the descriptions related to that category will be added to the second select menu, and so on. Same goes for deselecting. I want it to be reactive.

I have found these:

https://github.com/sagalbot/vue-select
https://github.com/monterail/vue-multiselect

But I haven't been able to find a solution to do this with two multiple selects yet. Any pointers?

PS. There are not too many categories and descriptions, so I can load them all into the view so vue can play around with them. I don't need an ajax call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to populate the second select dynamically and update its data source based on events coming from the first one.

Here's a small sketch, I hope it helps.

```
<template>
  <div class="root">
    <!-- initial select (options hardcoded) -->
    <select v-on:change="populate($event)" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="1">One</option>
      <option value="2">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select>
      <!-- options variable is reactive -->
      <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">{{option.text}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Selects',
  data () {
    return {
      options: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    populate (event) {
      const options = []
      // iterate over the selected options
      // event.target.selectedOptions is a HTMLCollection 

      Array.from(event.target.selectedOptions).forEach(item => {
        // or whatever logic you need
        options.push({
          value: item.value,
          text: `You have selected ${item.text}`
        })
      })

      // update the options attribute to trigger re-rendering
      this.options = options
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> Later EDIT
>
> jsfiddle here -> https://jsfiddle.net/bpgp11da/

Comment: Thanks a lot, will give this a try and see if I can make it work :)

Comment: Any fiddle perhaps so I can see it in action? Couldn't get it to work myself.

Comment: Added one in the main message. What's your setup?